# gulp.watch não executa task

Tags: javascript, gulpjs

## Introdução

Estou utlizando o gulp para automatizar minhas tarefas, estou usando gulp.watch para ele preprocessar o sass assim que verificar uma mudança no arquivo:

```
gulp.task('styles', function(){
        return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(sass({style: 'expanded'}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
    });

 gulp.task('watch', function() {
     gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
 });
```

Iniciando as tasks

```
gulp.task('default', ['express', 'watch'], function() {

});
```

No console

> $ gulp

Roda o servidor corretamente porém minha tarefa 'watch' não faz o pré-processamento ( apenas não acontece nd ), se eu ir direto na task `gulp watch` ele funciona corretamente.

#### Funcionando

Para funcionar

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', function(){
        gulp.start('styles');
    });
});
```

#### Problema

Gostaria de saber qual seria o problema para `gulp.watch` de não funcionar apenas passando os parâmetros conforme vi vários exemplos. Deixando dessa forma o código mais limpo.

```
gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
```

Comment: Conseguiste pôr isto a funcionar? Seria interessante ter uma resposta aqui para ajudar outros...

Comment: Tive que criar 2 watch um para o arquivo da raiz da pasta sass (*.scss) e o outro para demais arquivos dentro das pastas (**/*.scss)